# What has caused this strange growth on my euonymus?

Tags: diseases, shrubs, growth

We have an otherwise apparently healthy euonymus in our garden, but a couple of branches have gone very pale, wide and flat with tightly bunched stunted leaves on the end. What causes this and is it anything to worry about?

[image: Strange euonymus growth 1]
[image: Strange euonymus growth closeup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something called fasciation, caused by abnormal growth activity - as to what triggers that, there are 4 possible causes:- bacterial infection, viral infection, random genetic mutation, or injury through cold, mechanical damage or other damage. Those brown things might be adult scale - check the backs of other leaves, looking for white flecks - a heavy infestation of euonymus scale might have triggered the fasciation effect. If you find any, June is a good time to spray - Westland Resolva Bug Killer, or a systemic insecticide such as Provado Ultimate Bug Killer (more effective) should do the trick.

The fasciation may recur if its a result of viral activity, but usually, its an occasional event.

Comment: Accidental overspray from some herbicides can produce this growth as well.

Comment: Thanks! I picked off and squashed a couple of what looked like female scales but didn't find much else so I'll keep an eye on it and hope it doesn't recur.